# get parent object from within an object

Tags: php, object

Is this possible?

Let's say there are two objects of the same type:

`$object1->object2->property = 'xxxx';`

now this is done trough __set().
At this point I'm within object2's scope (which is a property of object1). How can I access object1 from that __set function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

`object1` isn't the parent, it's the container.
If you want access to an `object1` function from `object2`,
you must have a reference to `object1`.

Use this kind of pattern :

```
class class1 
{ 
   public $child; 
   public function __construct() 
   { 
      $this->child = new class2($this);
   }
} 

class class2 
{
   private $parent;
   public function __construct(class1 $parent) 
   {
      $this->parent = $parent; 
   }
}
```

Is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: yes, something like that, but I was hoping there's a way to do it without having to pass variables around :(

Comment: No way, and that's natural. You can have the same class (`class2`) used by multiple object. How can you choose which one is your 'parent' ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `parent::` from within the child class.

Comment: It's not a subclass; there's no inheritance. `object2` is simply one of `object1`'s properties.