# PHP - How to call function from an upstream object

Tags: php

I have a DB interface object, DBI, that requires authentication.  I have an object, foo, that doesn't extend anything. I also have a class bar that extends the DBobject  If I have an instance of foo that is a member of bar thus:

```
$b->$f=new foo;
```

How can I call somefunction() in $b from a function inside the foo class?  I've tried making the somefunction() static, but I don't want the authentication info sprinkled throughout my code.  And if I try having foo extend the DBI or bar classes, I wind up with an issue including the files and my foo __construct function fails because the bar class is not found. Is there another construct similar to extends/parent:: that I can use with objects that are just instances amongst each other?

Comment: I guess the idea is, a function in foo needs info from the DB, is there a way to access the DBI functions through something like $f->b->DBI ?

Answer (score 1):

The way that I've done this in the past, is create the Foo object within the Bar object within the __construct().  Then utilize the __call magic method to intercept the methods and see where it is.  So the code could look something like this:

```
public function __call($sMethod, $aArgs) {

    if(method_exists($this, $sMethod){
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $sMethod), $aArgs);
    }

    } elseif(method_exists($this->foo, $sMethod)) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->foo, $sMethod), $aArgs);
    }

}

public function __construct() {

    $this->foo = new foo();

}
```

Then you can call the functions from either foo or bar, even though they are not extended.  Just a though, maybe there is an easier way to do this.

** EDIT **
The benefit to this is you don't need to specify whether or not you are calling a method from foo or from bar, they will just "work".

** EDIT **

Based on the comments, you want to do this, correct?  Because based on the code below, if you run it it works correctly.

```
class foobar {

    public function test() {
         echo 'This is a test';
    }

}

class foo extends foobar {

}

class bar {

}

$bar = new bar();
$bar->foo = new foo();

$bar->foo->test();
```

or the alternative:

```
class foobar {

    public function test() {
        echo 'This is a test';
    }

}

class foo extends foobar {

}

class bar {

public function testFooBar() {

        $this->foo->test();

    }

}

$bar = new bar();
$bar->foo = new foo();

$bar->testFooBar();
```

Both work at long as you know the property name you are setting for the object.

Comment: So the question is, how can $this->foo->someFunction() call an inherited function like $this->someInheritedFunction() where $this is an instance of bar which extends DBI ?  The typical thing would be to call DBI::someInheritedFunction(), but this isn't working because I'm getting a class not found when I try to create an instance of bar within foo->someFunction().

Comment: Hmmm, so I must have been confused on your original question.  But is there a reason why you cannot do one of these things:  1)  Use a global in the code for the bar object (outside of the obvious, globals are evil statement), or 2) Create an object of bar within the construct of foo?  Or are you literally wanting $this to reference bar within foo?

Comment: Also, don't forget when you extend an object to use parent::__construct() within the extending class.  All properties should be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `call_user_func` and `call_user_func_array`, if you want to access methods and properties of the container object (not parent class), you need a reference to it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707460/get-parent-object-from-within-an-object) is a similar post.

Comment: Ah, this is what I was looking for... I just couldn't think of how to say it.  The link you provided solved my problem.